# Error installing OSX El Capitan

Tags: hard-drive, macos, install, error

I am trying to install OSX El Capitan in a Mac Mini but I get the error:

> **OS X could not be installed on your computer!**
>
> A disk with a mount point is required
>
> Quit the installer to restart your computer and try again.

I had formated the disk trying to fix the error and I getting this:
[image]